# LINQ to JSON - Unable to `.Select` child data into parent object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to parse some JSON into a class that has another class as one of it's properties. I am using Newtonsoft.Json as my JSON parser.

```
private class OrderModel
{
  public string OrderId {get; set;}
  public string OrderDescription {get; set;}
  public List<OrderDetailModel> OrderItems {get; set;} // Collection of OrderDetails
}

private class OrderDetailModel
{
  public string ProductId {get; set;}
  public string ProductName {get; set;}
  public decimal UnitPrice {get; set;}
  public int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

**Here is some sample JSON**

```
{
  ... //JSON data above here
  "transactionData": {
    "orders": [{
        "orderId": 111,
        "orderDescription": "Giant Food Mart",
        "orderItems": [{
            "productId": 65,
            "productName": "Dried Beef",
            "unitPrice": 10.00,
            "quantity": 7
          },
          {
            "productId": 23,
            "productName": "Carrots",
            "unitPrice": 1.25,
            "quantity": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "orderId": 112,
        "orderDescription": "Bob's Corner Variety",
        "orderItems": [{
            "productId": 523,
            "productName": "Red Licorice",
            "unitPrice": 0.50,
            "quantity": 27
          },
          {
            "productId": 321,
            "productName": "Gummy Worms",
            "unitPrice": 1.50,
            "quantity": 50
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ... //JSON data below here
}
```

My C# code to populate the objects with the JSON data

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
var transactionData = parsedJson["transactionData"]; // Jump to the transactionData node
var orders = transactionData
  .Select(x => new OrderModel
  {
    OrderId = (string)x["orderId"],
    OrderDescription = (string)x["orderDescription"],
    OrderItems = x["orderItems"].Select(y => new OrderDetailModel
    {
      ProductId  = (string)y["productId"], // not being recognized
      ProductName = (string)y["productName"], // not being recognized
      UnitPrice = (decimal)y["unitPrice"], // not being recognized
      Quantity = (int)y["quantity"] // not being recognized
    }).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

The problem is when I try and populate the `OrderDetailModel`. None of the properties of `ObjectDetailModel` are being recognized by intellisense.

Is there something wrong with my LINQ statement that I am missing? I wanted to use this method of populating the `OrderModel` and `OrderDetailModel` objects because the property names did not have to match the JSON property names. I was hoping to do the mapping in the LINQ Lambda statement.

**UPDATE** To help clarify an answer some of the comments. I can't even compile the code. As soon as I try an type in one of the properties from `OrderDetailModel` it is not recognized.

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
var transactionData = parsedJson["transactionData"]; // Jump to the transactionData node
var orders = transactionData
  .Select(x => new OrderModel
  {
    OrderId = (string)x["orderId"],
    OrderDescription = (string)x["orderDescription"],
    OrderItems = x["orderItems"].Select(y => new OrderDetailModel
    {
      //properties for OrderDetailModel not recognized here
    }).ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Is there a reason why this Lambda statement shouldn't work?

Comment: can you  use JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject ?

Comment: Try using `.Include()` to include OrderItems's OrderlModel

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if `transactionData` actualy contains these arrays?

Comment: May not be the issue, but you should take the comma out after Quantity. I'm trying to grasp the question... You mean that ProductId, etc, are not showing up on Intellisense? Are they being populated when you run the code? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: Answering some comments ... I could try `JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject` but my class names would have to match the JSON field names which I would rather not have to do. I am not familiar with how to use `.Include()` and what it does. Any examples? If I only try to populate the `OrderModel` and not the child `OrderDetailsModel` and remove the code for obtaing the OrderDetails the code works. So I know the data is there and is being picked up. And why the downvote? No explanation?

Comment: @webworm use **JsonProperty** and pass names of json fields there

Comment: Shouldn't it be transactionData["orders"].Select ?

Comment: Also OrderItems is of type OrderDetail not OrderDetailModel

Comment: Thanks for the correction. so many typos going from actual code to example code. the node `transactionData` holds the `orders` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the LINQ statement to read your JSON, you grabbed the transactionData but did not get the orders node below it. See the comments where I outline a few changes:

```
var orders = transactionData["orders"]
     .Select(x => new OrderModel
     {
         OrderId = (int)x["orderId"],
         OrderDescription = (string)x["orderDescription"],
         OrderItems = x["orderItems"]
         .Select(y => new OrderDetailModel
         {
            ProductId = (string)y["productId"],
            ProductName = (string)y["productName"], 
            UnitPrice = (decimal)y["unitPrice"], // casting to decimal but you have a string
            Quantity = (int)y["quantity"]
          }).ToList()
      });

public class OrderModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetailModel> OrderItems { get; set; } // Collection of OrderDetails
    }



public class OrderDetailModel
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bcR7Io

Comment: So the statement must be correct if you got it to work. Still cannot understand why, on my environment, the properties of `OrderDetailModel` are not being recognized in the LINQ statement. Still thanks for confirming the statement should work!

Comment: @webworm Look at the select on your OrderItems = x["orderItems"]
         .Select(y => new OrderDetail //you called this OrderDetailModel not OrderDetail.

Comment: But that is what the class is named`OrderDetailModel`. How is it working if you are referring to it as `OrderDetail`?

Comment: @webworm I'll update the answer with classes I used. I'll also copy and paste into a .Net Fiddle.

Comment: @webworm updated with correct classes, and a .Net Fiddle Demo.

Comment: Awesome example. Thank you! Wish I could give you more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the class Names are different than one in your question.

You have declared classes as `Order` and `OrderDetails` and in the code you are using `OrderModel` and `OrderDetailModel`.

Use one name and make classes protected or something not private.

The solution to your problem is to use following class structure and use `JsonConvert`.

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("transactionData")]
    public TransactionData TransactionData { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionData
{
    [JsonProperty("orders")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}
public class Order
{

    [JsonProperty("orderId")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("orderDescription")]
    public string OrderDescription { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("orderItems")]
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderItems { get; set; } // Collection of OrderDetails
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("productId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("productName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("unitPrice")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And then Desrialize

```
 string jsonResponse = @"{
                  'transactionData': {
                    'orders': [{
                        'orderId': 111,
                        'orderDescription': 'Giant Food Mart',
                        'orderItems': [{
                            'productId': 65,
                            'productName': 'Dried Beef',
                            'unitPrice': 10.00,
                            'quantity': 7
                          },
                          {
                            'productId': 23,
                            'productName': 'Carrots',
                            'unitPrice': 1.25,
                            'quantity': 100
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        'orderId': 112,
                        'orderDescription': 'Bob\'s Corner Variety',
                        'orderItems': [{
                            'productId': 523,
                            'productName': 'Red Licorice',
                            'unitPrice': 0.50,
                            'quantity': 27
                          },
                          {
                            'productId': 321,
                            'productName': 'Gummy Worms',
                            'unitPrice': 1.50,
                            'quantity': 50
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }";
 var transactionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonResponse);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in the class names. I corrected it. This looks to solve the issue regarding naming my class names the same as the JSON properties. I would still like to figure out why the LINQ statement wasn't working but this is a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: It is because you declared DTO's as **private** may be. @webworm remove that **private** access modifier on the class and try using LINQ it will work

Comment: I replaced with `public` and then removed access modifiers. Same result.